# graphicmagick not showing text of a wmf

Tags: graphicsmagick

On Linux I am trying to convert a wmf file to a ping file with GraphicsMagick.
However some text is not shown in the png file.
Example: Original (opened with LibreOffice draw :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bs0C.png)
then the rendered picture by graphicsmagick:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17cEQ.png)

the command is this:

> gm convert -density 1200x1200 "100MHZ EM2 HPF 061221.WMF" Test2.png

Here are the original files:
[Original Files](https://my.hidrive.com/share/jtsblavn3q)

Thanks,
Johannes

Comment: I don't understand. You say you want to convert a WMF to a PNG yet you post two PNGs. Please share the WMF - you can use Google Drive or Dropbox or similar if Imgur can't handle it.

Comment: Ok, my intention was to show the effect, not the original files. But OK, I can share the original files:

Comment: You should read this post about images in questions:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved this yet, but did a fair bit of research that I wanted to share in case it helps you or someone else work it out.

I ran `strings` on your WMF file and it appears to refer to `Courier New` font in there, so I am guessing the font is not found on your Alpine installation.

I found you can install Microsoft fonts using:

```
apk --no-cache add msttcorefonts-installer fontconfig 
update-ms-fonts
fc-cache -f
```

But **GraphicsMagick** appears to ignore them, until you edit its config file at `/usr/lib/GraphicsMagick-1.3.36/config/type.mgk` so that it includes Windows fonts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<typemap>
   <include file="type-ghostscript.mgk" />
   <include file="type-windows.mgk" />
</typemap>
```

That makes it include this file `/usr/lib/GraphicsMagick-1.3.36/config/type-windows.mgk`

Once you have done that, you can run your command with debugging enabled like this and see that it actually finds the fonts now:

```
gm convert -debug all -density 144x144  Input.WMF Test2.png
```

That said, I still can't see why your text doesn't come out - I may take a further look tomorrow with fresh eyes.

Comment: Hi, I did what you said, and the result was exactly as you expected... The debug output is quite big (80MB), so I didn't upload it. If you need it, please let me know. I also want to thank you for your effort, because this is a problem that obviously very seldon occurs.. Thank you.

Actually I found not many programs supporting this file, inkspace e.g. totaly creates rubish, so do all online tools that I tried. Only LibreOffice draw has a good view. But if you use the headless option the resolution is by far too low....